# reverse the serial number of a grouped query

Tags: mysql

The following query orders votes based on how many times users voted... I would like to know the # in the queue of the specific user.

```
SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number, user_id, COUNT(slug_owner) as cnt 
FROM `votes_queue`,(SELECT @s:= 0) AS s 
GROUP BY slug_owner
ORDER BY cnt DESC 

serial_number | user_id | cnt 
3 | 19 | 8
2 | 14 | 4
1 | 13 | 2
```

Essentially i need the numbers in the serial_number column to be reversed so I can tell that user 13 is #3 based on votes ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the serial numbers after generating the ordered count:

```
SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number, temp.*
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(slug_owner) as cnt 
    FROM `votes_queue`,
    GROUP BY slug_owner
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
) temp, (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
```

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The serial numbers are not reversed because `GROUP BY` and variables don't mix.  An `ORDER BY` is fine.  You can use @hjpotter92's solution, but the following also fixes the problem:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as serial_number, t.*
FROM (SELECT serial_number, user_id, COUNT(slug_owner) as cnt 
      FROM `votes_queue`
      GROUP BY slug_owner
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

I think the performance is the same.  I am offering this answer just to clarify what the actual problem is.

Comment: I went with @hjpotter92's answer. Thanks for sharing a second solution. Hopefully it will benefit others.